# Why do I have so many badges?

Tags: support, badges

According to my user page on meta, I have 1 Great Answer badge, 2 Nice Answer badges, and 2 Good Answer badges. But I've only got five answers, and only one has ten upvotes. Why so many badges?

[image]

Comment: Because, gosh darnit, you're so fabulous, why not have all those badges?

Comment: @random: Well, that's what I figured, but I wanted to make sure. :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[What's your favorite programmer cartoon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84556/whats-your-favorite-programmer-cartoon) got moved here, then moved back to SO.  You got awarded the Great Answer badge when it was moved.

Answer (score 5):

My guess is that an uberthread got moved here and then deleted (or moved back). Badges are never deleted, but you are in the hole for all of those. So, you will need to get 2 Great Answer badges to actually net 1 now.

Comment: So if I get awarded a Great Answer badge in the future, the system will realize _then_ that I should only have one, not two?

Comment: @Graeme: You betcha.

Comment: @Graeme: There's no IF sir, *when* you get awarded a Great Answer badge...