# Bug: Great Answer badge with no answers?

Tags: bug, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do I have so many badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18448/why-do-i-have-so-many-badges)

I just got a Great Answer badge on this site but I have not answered any questions. Go look https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/16204/epochwolf

Possible explaination: [Why do I have so many badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18448/why-do-i-have-so-many-badges)

Comment: You found your own dupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had an answer on the question, [What’s your favorite “programmer” cartoon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84556/whats-your-favorite-programmer-cartoon/84747#84747)

You scored the Great Answer badge when it was on SO. Then it was migrated here, and you clocked the badge here. You kept that badge when it was moved back.

You don't lose any badge you earn. Unless it was Beta.